# How do you print Xcode Swift source code in color?

Tags: xcode, printing, colors

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 4 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. My printer is the HP Color Officejet Pro 8620. When I attempt to print from Xcode menu File>Print, I un-check the Black & White in the print dialog-box; however, it still prints the source code in black and white.

My printer prints correctly in color in other applications such as Mac's TextEdit, etc. (but not in Xcode).

I greatly appreciate it if anyone has a solution or recommendation for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the print dialog sheet appears, try selecting the default or basic theme.

[image: Select Print Theme for Xcode]